# Exam Question some confusion?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, square-numbers

Given
$$ y=x+\sqrt{ x+ \sqrt {x + \sqrt {x +.....}} } $$

Then y(2)=?

A)4 only B)1 only C) 4 or 1 D) undefined..

My answer is

Taking root both side
$$ {\sqrt y} = {\sqrt {x+\sqrt{ x+ \sqrt {x + \sqrt {x +.....}} }}} $$

$$ {\sqrt y} = {\sqrt {x + \sqrt y}}  $$

$$ y=x+ \sqrt{y} $$

$$ x=2 $$
$$ y=2+\sqrt{y}$$
$$  y-2 = \sqrt{y}   $$
$$  (y-2)^2 =y   $$
$$ y^2 +4 -4y =y   $$
$$ y^2 -5y+4=0$$

$$y=4 or 1 $$

But we know the value of the square root always greater than 0.
$$y=2 +\sqrt{....}$$

so the value is always greater than 2.

my question is in the above solution where I did wrong so I get the value 1?

Comment: The value is 4.

Comment: When you start squaring you may introduce spurious roots. Consider this example: Let $a=2$. Therefore $a^2=4$. Hence $a=\pm 2$.

Comment: @ancient mathematician : It is true, but I don't think this is the problem here.

Comment: @JeanMarie Are you sure. I think the line $y-2=\sqrt{y}$ is correct, and only has the root $y=4$, but on squaring we lose precision and pick up the extra (spurious) root $1$.

Comment: @ancient mathematician My point is that all spurious roots can be eliminated afterwards.